# Use a Go GitHub repo

Tags: github, go

I have Go installed, setup, and running hello world; I followed [these directions](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). My workspace is organized as follows:

```
gocode/
    bin/
    pkg/
    src/
        github.com/
            my_username/
                hello/
                    hello.go
            anomalyzer/
                algorithms.go
                ...
                README.md
```

I would like to start using Go code from a forked GitHub repo, [lytics/anomalyzer](https://github.com/lytics/anomalyzer). How can I do this? I forked the repo and setup a local clone in `github.com/anomalyzer/` as shown above. But from the `github.com/anomalyzer/` dir I try `go install` and get the error message `algorithms.go:5:2: cannot find package "github.com/drewlanenga/govector" in any of: ...(lists my GOPATH)`. It looks like I need to also clone the `github.com/drewlanenga/govector`, do I? Is there an automated way to get all the package dependencies?

Comment: When forking something, I like to keep it in the path you'd get if you `go get` the project.  Of course it depends on the project, but if the project uses more than one package, you'll be stuck rewriting import paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch remote packages, run the `go get` command. Because the `go get` command automatically fetches dependencies and does not fetch a package that already have have, you can run

```
go get github.com/lytics/anomalyzer
```

to get everything setup including the `github.com/drewlanenga/govector` package.

Comment: Where should I run this from? Was cloning the anomalizer repo necessary?